# Exists operand in Sql

Tags: sql

I have a `select` query that uses the `exists` keyword.
The query works as needed, but I don't know how it happens.
According to my understanding the query should return many results but actually it returns single result (as needed).

This is the design of the sql statement:

```sql
select *
from MY_TABLE t1 where t1.version_nr=(
 select max(t2.version_nr) from MY_TABLE t2
 where t2.user_ID= 123456
 and (exists 
     (select 1 from MY_SECOND_TABLE mySecondTable 
     cross join THIRD_TABLE thirdTable where t1.user_ID=thirdTable.id and 
     mySecondTable.test_id=t2.id 
     and mySecondTable.parent_ID=thirdTable.second_table_parent_id )));
```

As you can see there is sub query into the main query.
In my data, the sub query returns result of=3 (`version_nr`).
When I run the query with this result: `select * from MY_TABLE t1 where t1.version_nr=3`, I get many results.
And if I run with the sub query **that contains exists block** it returns single result.

According to my understanding the query should be like that (the additional condition is in bold):

```sql
select *
from MY_TABLE t1 where **t1.user_ID= 123456 AND** t1.version_nr=(
 select max(t2.version_nr) from MY_TABLE t2
 where t2.user_ID= 123456
 and (exists 
     (select 1 from MY_SECOND_TABLE mySecondTable 
     cross join THIRD_TABLE thirdTable where t1.user_ID=thirdTable.id and 
     mySecondTable.test_id=t2.id 
     and mySecondTable.parent_ID=thirdTable.second_table_parent_id )));
```

Can someone help me to understand why the "exists" operand cause to it (do the same as the query I think is correct?)

Comment: The "max" returns result 3.
So, if when I replace the subquery with result 3 (t1.version_nr=3)
it returns me many results, so, I think it's not related to it.

Comment: If your subquery actually returns 3, then it should give you as many rows as `select * from MY_TABLE t1 where t1.version_nr = 3`, there is no magic filtering here. If it doesn't, then it either doesn't return 3, or your tool are not showing you all the rows. Or, you have messed your parentheses, and are actually running something like `where t1.version_nr=(...) and exists(...)`.

Comment: Your subquery includes this clause `where t1.user_ID=thirdTable.id`.  Since `t1` is the main query's table, this is (partially) cross-correlating the main query with the subquery beyond just the condition that  `t1.version_nr = 3`.

Comment: but if I leaves just this clause : where t1.user_ID=thirdTable.id,
the query returns many result. so, maybe there is another reason that cause it?

Comment: There isn't. The inner joins inside your subquery prevent it from returning 3 for most rows of `MY_TABLE`, even though many of these rows contain 3 in `version_nr`. So your subquery [does not return 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68087403/exists-operand-in-sql#comment120341165_68087403) when you think it does.

Comment: I still don't understand how the clause: where t1.user_ID=thirdTable.id affects the main query.
If the subquery select "max" function it returns any number. 
How it's related to the conditions into the subquery that filter the result and take from the retrieved records the max version_nr?

Comment: It does not affect the main query. It affects the subquery. It makes the subquery return `null` for some rows of the main query.

Comment: But there are many records in DB that have version_nr=3.
So, why the main query isn't return them?

Comment: Please pay attention that the main query has subquery that has another subquery into it.
So, the conditions in the subquery of the subquery(grandchild query)  should not affect the main query, just the first subquery (child query)

Comment: The grandchild query fails its `where t1.user_ID=thirdTable.id`. That means the child query fails its `exists()`. That means the child query has no rows to `max()`. That means the child query has to return `null` to the main query as the result of its `max()`, because `max()` returns `null` when there is nothing to max. That means the current row of the main query tests `where t1.version_nr=null` which is never true. That means the current row of the main query is excluded even if it has 3 in `version_nr`.

Comment: The comment of  https://stackoverflow.com/users/109122/rbarryyoung  (third comment), is the correct answer.

I can't flag it as correct answer because it's impossible for answer by comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is the third comment (in the comments list above) of RBarryYoung:

"Your subquery includes this clause where t1.user_ID=thirdTable.id.
Since t1 is the main query's table, this is (partially) cross-correlating the main query with the subquery beyond just the condition that t1.version_nr = 3." – (RBarryYoung)